# Rails, in a route like /books/:slug, :to => 'books#show', slug: /.*?/ what is slug: /.*?/ doing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slug

I have come across a route like `/books/:slug, :to => 'books#show', slug: /.*?/` in an application I have been working on. I am curious what does this part do `slug: /.*?/` ?

Comment: Its [segment constraints](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#segment-constraints) and the `/.*?/` is a regex fed as a format

Comment: oh segement constraints, thanks alot for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Its a misguided attempt at slugging.

It creates a route that matches:

```
/books/1
/books/abcd-absc
```

But not:

```
/books/1/2
/books/abcd-absc/2
```

`slug: /.*?/` is a completely pointless regex constraint since `.*` matches everything.

The end result is a route that does the exact same thing as the `GET /books/:id` generated by the conventional `resources :books` does except that the parameter is now named `:slug` (woopty do!) - the main reason its so misguided is that this route will conflict with the former.

You can really just do simple slugging that looks up a record by id or slug with:

```
@book = Book.where(id: params[:id]).or(Book.where(slug: params[:id])).first!
```

Comment: You are right but I only wanted to know what it is doing. Anyhow Thanks!